# Transaction.Current is slow in x86

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, transactions

-- On 64 bit it works properly

**Results:**

- Before: 0
- After: 7031
- Last: 0

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Before: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

Transaction transaction = Transaction.Current;

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("After: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

stopwatch.Reset();
Transaction transaction2 = Transaction.Current;

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Last: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

Console.Read();
```

Comment: Unable to replicate problem, executed the program in the question for both x86 and x64, and they both run fast. See if antivirus has a finger in this, try disabling it?

Comment: Aside: `ElapsedMilliseconds` will always be `0` (or **very** close to it) after creating a new `StopWatch`. There's no point writing the `before` bit.